# Proving that at least one of G and its dual graph G* has a vertex v of degree at most 3.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Recently, I read one literature and saw a property about the planar graph. I thought about it for a long time without thinking out the reason:

> Let $G$ be a **planar graph**. Then  at least one of $G$ and its
> **dual graph** $G^*$ has a vertex $v$ of degree **at most 3**.

I know some  conclusions that may be useful.

1. Every planar graph has a vertex of degree at most $5$.
2. The number of edges in a maximal planar graph is $3n-6$.

Definition of **dual graph**:

Given a plane graph $G$, one can define a second graph $G^∗$ as follows. Corresponding to each face $f$ of $G$ there is a vertex $f^∗$ of G∗ , and corresponding to each edge $e$ of $G$ there is an edge $e^∗$ of $G^∗$ . Two vertices $f^∗$ and $g^∗$ are joined by the edge $e^∗$ in $G^∗$ if and only if their corresponding faces $f$ and $g$ are separated by the edge $e$ in $G$.
Observe that if e is a cut edge of G, then $f = g$, so $e^∗$ is a loop of G∗; conversely,if e is a loop of $G$, the edge $e^∗$ is a cut edge of $G^∗$. The graph $G^*$ is called **dual** of G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$, $m$ the number of edges of $G$, and $r$ the number of faces of $G$. We use the notation $\mathcal{E}(f)$ for the number of edges on the face $f$.

We will assume that $G^*$ has no vertex of degree $3$ or less, and prove that $G$ must then have a vertex of degree at most $3$.

If $G^*$ has no vertex of degree $3$ or less, than every face of the original graph $G$ has at least $4$ edges on its boundary.
Since every edge appears twice on a face boundary (either once on two different faces, or twice on one face if it is a cut edge), we get that:

$$\sum_{f\text{ a face of $G$}} \mathcal{E}(f) = 2m$$

We have assumed that $G^*$ has minimum degree at least $4$, so this gives:

$$2m = \sum_{f\text{ a face of $G$}} \mathcal{E}(f) \geq 4r$$

By substituting $r\leq \frac{m}{2}$ into Euler's Formula ($n-m+r = 2$), we get that:

$$2 = n-m+r \leq n-m + \frac{m}{2}$$

Rearrange this to bound the number of edges as $m\leq 2n-4$.

Since $2m = \sum_{v\in V(G)}d(v)$, we get that the sum of the degrees is bounded by:

$$\sum_{v\in V(G)}d(v) = 2m \leq 4n-8 < 4n$$

The sum of the degrees of $G$ is less than $4n$, so the average degree of $G$ is less than $4$ (the average degree is the sum of the degrees divided by $n$). This means there is at least one vertex with degree less than $4$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I  also find its equivalent proposition.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711976/show-that-in-a-planar-graph-no-triangles-there-exists-a-vertex-with-degree-l?rq=1